# Change from YUY to MJPG format

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net, mjpeg

I have a web cam that's capable of running both YUY and MJPG color spaces. This camera default  is YUY, what do i need to alter or add in my DirectShow graph to start the camera in MJPG programmatically? My code is very similar to the typical graph setup, resembling the DxSnap example found in the DirectShow.Net sample directory.
documentation is scarce regarding this, the only sample i've seen is displaying the capture pin property page and changing it through that UI, however my technique needs to be implemented programmatically. 
any help, guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Here is my graph construction:

```
/// <summary> build the capture graph for grabber. </summary>
    private void SetupGraph(DsDevice dev, int iFrameRate, int iWidth, int iHeight)
    {
        int hr;

        ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;

        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 capGraph = null;

        // Get the graphbuilder object
        m_graphBuilder = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
        m_mediaCtrl = m_graphBuilder as IMediaControl;
        try
        {
            // Get the ICaptureGraphBuilder2
            capGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();

            // Get the SampleGrabber interface
            sampGrabber = (ISampleGrabber)new SampleGrabber();

            // Start building the graph
            hr = capGraph.SetFiltergraph(m_graphBuilder);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Add the video device
            hr = m_graphBuilder.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(dev.Mon, null, "Video input", out capFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = (IBaseFilter)sampGrabber;
            ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

            // Add the frame grabber to the graph
            hr = m_graphBuilder.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Get list of video compressors on the system
            DsDevice[] videoCompressors = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoCompressorCategory);

            IBaseFilter videoCompressorFilter = null;
            string videoCompressor = "MJPEG Compressor";
            foreach (DsDevice compressor in videoCompressors)
            {
                if (compressor.Name == videoCompressor)
                {
                    object obj = null;
                    Guid bfGuid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
                    compressor.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref bfGuid, out obj);
                    videoCompressorFilter = obj as IBaseFilter;
                    break; // Found the compressor - stop looking for it
                }

            }

            if (videoCompressorFilter != null)
            {
                hr = m_graphBuilder.AddFilter(videoCompressorFilter, videoCompressor);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }


            // If any of the default config items are set
            if (iFrameRate + iHeight + iWidth > 0)
            {
                SetConfigParms(capGraph, capFilter, iFrameRate, iWidth, iHeight);
            }


            hr = capGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, capFilter, null, baseGrabFlt);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);

        }
        finally
        {

            if (sampGrabber != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampGrabber);
                sampGrabber = null;
            }
            if (capGraph != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capGraph);
                capGraph = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveSizeInfo(ISampleGrabber sampGrabber)
    {
        int hr;

        // Get the media type from the SampleGrabber
        AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();
        hr = sampGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType(media);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        if ((media.formatType != FormatType.VideoInfo) || (media.formatPtr == IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown ISampleGrabber Media Format");
        }

        // Grab the size info
        VideoInfoHeader videoInfoHeader = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(media.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));
        m_videoWidth = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Width;
        m_videoHeight = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Height;
        m_stride = m_videoWidth * (videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.BitCount / 8);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        media = null;
    }
    private void ConfigureSampleGrabber(ISampleGrabber sampGrabber)
    {
        AMMediaType media;
        int hr;

        // Set the media type to Video/RBG24
        media = new AMMediaType();
        media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        media.subType = MediaSubType.MJPG;
        media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        hr = sampGrabber.SetMediaType(media);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        media = null;

        // Configure the samplegrabber
        hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(this, 1);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
```

function for frame callback:

```
    void OnFrameDone()
    {
        try
        {
            int w = Width;
            int h = Height;
            if (((w < 32) || (h < 32)))
            {                   
                return;
            }

            int stride = w * 3;

            lock (this)
            {
                GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(savedArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                int scan0 = (int)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                scan0 += (h - 1) * stride;
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(w, h, -stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)scan0);


                //switch (FrameDirection)
                //{
                //    case VideoDir.Portrait:
                //        b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                //        break;

                //    case VideoDir.Landscape:
                //        b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                //        b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                //        break;

                //}

                if(FrameCaptureComplete != null)
                    FrameCaptureComplete(b);

                handle.Free();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }


        return;

    }
```

Comment: You may want to use [IC Imaging Control SDK](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/products/software/sdks/icimagingcontroltis/) for interfacing camera in .Net

Comment: it says its only free with their products... i am up to any language... i can create a C# wrapper out of just about anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout all this trial and error, my research reaches a  conclusion that my efforts were not exactly failed attempts. The Microsoft MJPEG Decompressor is not working above 3MP resolution, i was attempting to run the graph at 5MP. Using a 3rd party MJPEG Compressor that was capable of running 5MP fixed all the issues i was experiencing.

Thank you Roman for your help.

Comment: That's right, and this is why it would be so helpful if you posted full media type (with resolution) right onto the question. I believe the limit is 1920x1080 or close to that. Stock M-JPEG Decompressor is a very old codec wrapped into DirectShow filter, nothing advanced there. Literally anything else beats it easily in terms of caps and performance. [More info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/1476b190-b563-4020-b2c5-b3e78b860da0) for those who might want to read up more on this.

Comment: you're absolutely right Roman, i had no idea the resolution was the culprit... live and learn on both sides of this question... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the camera does it in a non-standard way, it should expose `IAMStreamConfig` interface on its output pin, where you can select format by providing the media type of interest into SetFormat method. Once done, keep building graph and connecting the pin downstream.

Comment: that was my first guess, i just haven't seen a C# example.... I'm going to look into the c++ documentation on implementation

Comment: I've done some research and im still having issues setting the format to mjpeg... i would assume this property is set through the AMMediaType [MajorType], [SubType] and [FormatType]... but everything i have tried has failed.... should i be working with the copied data from [v] instead of directly setting [media]?:

Marshal.PtrToStructure(media.formatPtr, v);

Comment: if i set:

media.subType = MediaSubType.MJPG;

i get:

no combination of intermediate filters could be found

Comment: It is hard to tell, you don't give any info. If JPEG compression is available the standard way, you should be able to see JPEG media types either `1` enumerating media types on source filter output pin, or `2` enumerating IAMStreamConfig capabilities. However, there might be custom implementations that require that JPEG compression is activated in a vendor specific way.

Comment: i think i may need to implement a smartT filter in this graph... i ran into a similar situation in the past. as far as providing information what would you need?  ill post my graph setup above...

Comment: Output from `IPin::EnumMediaTypes` + `IAMStreamConfig::GetStreamCaps` would be helpful. If the camera supports MJPG, it should show it somewhere in those methods.

Comment: ok, ill try... i know the camera is capable of running in MJPG color space... i can manually change it to MJPG from the video capture pin property page in DS....

Comment: ok, something is wrong with my graph setup... 1, i'm connecting to the capture pin and it defaults to YUY.... in the DxSnap example the graph is connecting to the still pin and starting the camera in MJPG (what it seems). i need to run a few tests but i am getting 15fps on a 5MP camera (YUY runs at 3fps), so to me it seems like i am running in MJPG, i will confirm this shortly...

Comment: ok, everything is working as far as the MJPG format... but now that im running in this mode on the still pin in the DxSnap sample BufferCB is no longer firing unless i use:   hr = m_VidControl.SetMode(m_pinStill, VideoControlFlags.Trigger);
                    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );... i need this callback for other reasons.... any advice?

Comment: It is unclear what is going on, it seems you sovled the MJPG capture question. For the new non-working part there is just no info.

Comment: you have been a great help in giving direction Roman! I don't neccesarily need the exact graph setup i have above... i've been focusing on the DxSnap since it's the closest i have to a semi-working product... but i'm not getting any error in the SG configuration to alert me why the BufferCB would not be firing...

Comment: As a hint - when you already started the application, make sure to connect to the graph externally using GraphEdit/GraphStudio to verify the topology. Depending on how you build it, it might be looking not quite as you expect it and explain troubles. Not to say that its screenshot would be an important part of the question description.

Comment: i did save a graph edit file after i contructed the graph, before i ran it... but i'm not really sure what i should be looking for

Comment: Ok, i am running in mjpg with my new graph above (i can see this in SaveSizeInfo returning {47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71} "MJPG") and i have the SG running...now constructing the bitmap is the last part... my code above returns the bitmap and the properties look correct but its just a red X on my picturebox control???? i have a Delegate set up in the BufferCB pointing to the OnFrameDone...cant figure it out...(yet)

Comment: i awarded you the bounty simply for all your help. thank you.